# Sitecore Sites.Config

Tags: performance, configuration, sitecore, settings

In our team we have a Sitecore solution that we run locally. Some developers where noticing a high start up time, while other didn't.

After investigating the differences between the local config files, I've noticed that 1 particular setting was causing this high start up time.

The settings was located in the sites.config transform. When adding a transform to enablePreview to put the enablePreview to **False**, the start up time increased with more than **100%**. 
When removing this, the start up time was much better.

This seems pretty strange to me, because disabling the preview, should make your Sitecore solution faster right?

Anyone a good explanation for this?

Comment: Weird, since Removing this attribute means enablePreview=false (Default).
Probably its best to contact sitecore support for this

Answer (score 1):

To speed up the start up time you could, among other things, disable SPEAK precompilation. For an extensive list regarding developer productivity, read [this blog by John West](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2015/02/maximize-sitecore-developer-productivity.aspx).

Comment: This is NOT link only.  It gives a tip and a link to more info.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a couple months old, but try using the Sitecore debugger by appending `?sc_debug=1&sc_prof=1&sc_trace=1&sc_ri=1` to the end of your URL.

That will allow you to see anything that takes an exceptional amount of time to load.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that could increase startup time is to disable/decrease caching and disable indexing in your dev enviornment.

While in production it speeds up the performance of the site, it also slows down startup time. You can set the tweaks in Debug web.config transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that could increase start-up time is to disable caching and disable indexing for Master database because no need to indexing for master database in your dev environment.